# iOS 7 – hidden input accessory view is shown after bannerViewActionShouldBegin:willLeaveApplication:

Tags: ios, ios7, inputaccessoryview

It's a bit more complex than that, the sequence is:

- rotate the device from portrait to landscape back to portrait
- wait for an ad to show
- tap the ad
- hidden accessory view will appear over the ad

I've confirmed it happens after `-bannerViewActionShouldBegin:willLeaveApplication:` is called.

Has anyone seen this? If so, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have seen it. A partial fix is to set alpha to 0 for the input accessory view in `-bannerViewActionDidFinish:`. This will at least hide the input accessory view when the ad returns. This problem is supposed to be fixed in iOS 8.

Comment: Thank you, it still shows when the ad plays, any way to hide it then?

Comment: Not by any publically exposed methods, but you could set up a 500 ms or so timer to set alpha after `-bannerViewActionShouldBegin:willLeaveApplication:` is called. I've never tried this, though.